# Turn off Flashlight on Android Lollipop version

Tags: android, flashlight, android-5.1.1-lollipop

```
kCamera = Camera.open();
kCamera.Parameters cam1= k.Camera.getParameters();
cam1.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
kCamera.setParameters(cam1);
SurfaceTexture mPreviewTexture = new SurfaceTexture(0);
try {
     kCamera.setPreviewTexture(mPreviewTexture);
} catch {
}
mCam.startPreview();
```

This works fine, it opens flashlight.

But how can I turn off ?

Comment: I know the problem is solved. However Camera is deprecated from lollipop. (API 21). See this page: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FLASH_MODE_OFF)

> public static final String FLASH_MODE_OFF
>
> Added in API level 5 Flash will not be fired.
>
> Constant Value: "off"

So, you can define function like this:

```
public void turnOffFlashLight(Camera camera){
        Camera.Parameters cam1 = camera.getParameters();
        cam1.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        kCamera.setParameters(cam1);
    }
```

And then, use it when you need:

```
turnOffFlashLight(kCamera);
```